# Logging to SQL Server in bulks using log4net

Tags: c#, sql-server, log4net, sqlbulkcopy, adonetappender

I'm using log4net to log messages to a SQL Server database using the `AdoNetAppender`. I need to insert the logs in bulks. I've tried using the `batchSize` property of the appender, but as far as I can tell the result is something like:

```
conn.Open();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    comm.ExecuteNonReader();
}

conn.Close();
```

And this eventually translates to a bunch of Inserts. So if my batch size is for instance 500, then there will be 500 consecutive inserts.

My goal is for the bulks to be inserted in 1 insert statement. Like .NET's [`SqlBulkCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx).

Is it possible to achieve this result with log4net? Or do I have to implement my own custom appender to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write your own custom appender because log4net does not do this out of the box. You can just inherrit from the AdoNetAppender and override the `virtual protected void SendBuffer(IDbTransaction dbTran, LoggingEvent[] events)`

[AdoNetAppender.cs](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/Appender/AdoNetAppender.cs?view=markup)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up using the following implementatio
https://github.com/cneuwirt/rhino-commons/blob/master/Rhino.Commons/Logging/AsyncBulkInsertAppender.cs

Comment: Hi Peter, do you have an example of doing a bulk insert using IDbTransaction?

Comment: @dave sorry I don't have such example. Adding a transaction around the insert doesn't make sense in a logging scenario. A rollback can remove logentries.